# Unable to run intermediate image after updating

Tags: docker

I have upgraded to docker desktop 3.4.0 on windows 10 and the build out put has changed.  Intermediate container hashes are no longer listed in build output so I can't connect to the intermediate layers.

If I use the `--progress plain` flag then it outputs each stage like this:

```
#13 [build  2/10] WORKDIR /src
#13 sha256:7ca1a3c3d8a04cb964b2921644ff3dd028ed11e1079756eef968cf9e2631bccf
#13 CACHED
```

But that sha256 isn't an image, I can't run it.  The intermediary ones before were much shorter.

What has changed?  How do I get the hash of the intermediate layers?

Comment: This doesn't seem possible any more with the Buildkit backend (which is a shame, it's really useful when you need it).